# Can a Git client with VPN access act as a proxy to another client on the local network WITHOUT VPN access

Tags: git

I'm working at home on a Windows laptop with VPN access, and happily accessing the company's Git/Bitbucket repo.  I have another Mac laptop at home that does NOT have VPN access, but it CAN connect to the Windows laptop via my local network.  Is there a way to "set things up" so that I can access the Git repo from my Mac "through" the Windows laptop?

I can't find anything after hours of searching, but that could be because I'm not quite sure how best to phrase the question.  So hope this makes some sense...

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a "tunneled proxy".  Git supports multiple protocols, `git://`, `ssh://`, `http://` and `https://`.  Your search for a solution should be based on the protocol in use, not necessarily Git itself.

Comment: Or you could consider using an ssh tunnel, if at all possible.